# Select Event from Drop Down Menu - Javascript Only

Tags: javascript

I have tried this a hundred ways, need some help getting going. I did look at other people's questions and answers but have been unable to use any of them and get them to work. I have a drop down menu. I need to create an event, changing the color in a div for each of the options in the drop down menu. Code is below, I need to use Javascript only not JQuery.

Here is the HTML for the "menu"

```
   <select name="colorBlog" id="colors">
<option value = "Red">Red</option>
<option value = "Blue">Blue</option>
<option value = "Green">Green</option>
<option value = "Yellow">Yellow</option>    
<option value = "Pink">Pink</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should really show what you've tried. The simplest way would be to add to the `select` element `onchange="getElementById('the_div').style.backgroundColor = value;"`. I don't necessarily  recommend putting that much code in a handler attribute though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function changecolor() {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.color = colors.value
}

var colors = document.getElementById('colors');
colors.addEventListener('change', changecolor);
changecolor();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PYWBx/)